# TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer when I try to recognize a photo

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, keras

I want to test a trained model, I use keras and opencv, here is the code:

creating an argument parser and passing them

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
                help="path to input image we are going to classify")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
                help="path to trained Keras model")
ap.add_argument("-l", "--label-bin", required=True,
                help="path to label binarizer")
ap.add_argument("-w", "--width", type=int, default=28,
                help="target spatial dimension width")
ap.add_argument("-e", "--height", type=int, default=28,
                help="target spatial dimension height")
ap.add_argument("-f", "--flatten", type=int, default=-1,
                help="whether or not we should flatten the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

loading the input image and changing its size to the required one

```
image = cv2.imread(args['image'])
output = image.copy()
image = cv2.resize(image, (args['width'], args['height']))
# scaling the pixel values to the range
image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
# check whether you need to smooth the image and add the batch size
if args['flatten'] > 0:
    image = image.flatten()
    image = image.reshape((1, image.shape))

# otherwise, we work with CNN -- don't smooth the image
# and just add the package size
else:
    image = image.reshape((1, image.shape, image.shape,image.shape))

print(" loading network and label binarizer...")
model = load_model(args['model'])
lb = pickle.loads(open(args['label-bin'], "rb").read())

# recognizing the image
preds = model.predict(image)

# finding the index of the class label with the highest probability
# matches
i = preds.argmax(axis=1)
label = lb.classes_

text = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, preds * 100)
cv2.putText(output, text, (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7,
            (0, 0, 255), 2)

# showing the output image
cv2.imshow("Image", output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But I get the following error:

```
image = image.change the shape((1, Image.form, image.form,image.form))
TypeError: the 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The same thing I get `if args['flatten'] > 0`
Can someone help you figure out the problem?

Comment: You have double rounded brackets, which makes first argument a tuple. Remove double quotes and you are sorted.

Comment: @go2nirvana, I did this, but the error remained

Comment: @go2nirvana, I do this image = image.reshape(1, image.shape)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.